# How to dynamically change content inside Modal Bottomsheet android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have a Bottomsheet xml which contains two elements, *Follow* and *Copy link*.. when I click on *Follow*, it should be changed to *Unfollow* dynamically. I tried using *setText*, not worked.

Please guide me how to change text of bottomsheet dialogues.

Here is my Bottomsheet xml file

```
<LinearLayout app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="180dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#ffffff"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_follow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mode_follow_grey_24dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/followTView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Follow"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_copy"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:padding="16dp">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_copy_grey_24dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/copyLink"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:text="Copy link"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Bottomsheet *Java* code

```
    View bottomSheetView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_for_sharedposts, null);

            mDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
            mDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
            mDialog.show();

followBtnLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_follow);
followTView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.followTView);

followBtnLayout .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    followTView.setText("Unfollow");
}
});
```

But, the *Follow* Textview (I mean followTView) is not changing to *Unfollow*.
Please tell me where I have gone wrong...

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with boolean i have done it with my imageview.
Might help you

```
 //Initialize boolean as true by default
   public boolean showingFirst = true;

  holder.ivFavorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (showingFirst){
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Item added to favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.filled_heart);
                    showingFirst = false;
                }else {
                    holder.ivFavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite);
                    Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Item removed from favorite", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    showingFirst = true;
                }

            }
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Just a guess. Did you try to re-arrange the code? maybe the the click listener should load first before calling "mDialog.show()".

```
 View bottomSheetView = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.bottom_sheet_dialog_for_sharedposts, null);

        followBtnLayout = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet_follow);
        followTView = bottomSheetView.findViewById(R.id.followTView);

        followBtnLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                followTView.setText("Unfollow");
            }
        });

        mDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(mContext);
        mDialog.setContentView(bottomSheetView);
        mDialog.show();
```